# connect to mongodb using Morphia in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am trying to connect to MongoDb using Morphia in Java. I went through some tutorials as well as some question asked in stackoverflow. They all using "createDatastore" and this method is deprecated. There are two methods to create a datastore and both are deprected. What is the alternative to this method. The way I am using this as follows

```
    Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
    morphia.mapPackage("org.mongodb.morphia");
    final Datastore datastore = morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, mapper, "equity");
    TestData testData = new TestData ();
    testData.setAvg(new BigDecimal("500.02"));
    testData.setDate(Date.valueOf("2021-08-20"));

    datastore.save(testData );
```

**EDIT 1:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what version you're using but with [version 2.2](https://morphia.dev/morphia/2.2/quicktour.html#_setting_up_morphia), you would connect something like this:

```java
final Datastore datastore = Morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, "equity");
datastore.getMapper().mapPackage("org.mongodb.morphia");
```

Comment: I am using the latest one available on maven central i.e. 1.3.2 and there is no 2.2. is there any other place where I can find its JAR with dependencies?

Comment: 2.2.1 is the latest and is on maven central.  More details [here](https://morphia.dev/morphia/2.2/index.html)

Comment: Great.  Let me know how it goes.  2.x tried to clean up the API a bit but I'm not sure i got it right here and there (particularly this very question).  Still feels dirty to me.